# HTML Button with two actions. One of them to be delayed

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

First of all I would like to thank this forum for helping me out through other users previously answered questions. You guys rock!

This issue I couldn´t find an answer though.

I´m having this little .HTA page. It´s basically a status page that contains two iframes and a refresh button.
One of the iframes contains a .html page that upon reload is updated.
The other iframe contains a .htm page locally stored. This .htm page is auto-republished everytime a specifik excel document is saved.

So. I would like this refresh button to refresh the entire .hta (because it will refresh both iframes). But before that I would like the refresh button to open the excel document. This document is already programmed to run some macros which write the needed data, saves and closes excel (and hereby republishing the local .htm page). My problem is that this excel document is about 3 seconds to perform the actions, so I somehow need to delay the refresh.

Anyone knows how to add a delayed refresh action on top of my button onclick action "runprogram1"?

Hope it makes sense.

Here is my code so far: (edited out some private url).

```
<html>
 <head>
 <HTA:APPLICATION ID="webpad0"
 APPLICATIONNAME="webpad"
 BORDER="yes"
 INNERBORDER="no"
 CAPTION="yes"
 SELECTION="no"
 SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
 SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
 SYSMENU="yes"
 SCROLL="no"
 TITLEBAR="yes"
 ICON="ico.ico"
 NAVIGABLE="true"
 SCROLLFLAT="yes"
 SCROLL="no"></HTA:APPLICATION>

 <script language="vbscript">
 winWidth=600
 winHeight=800
 window.resizeto winWidth,winHeight
 centerX=(screen.width-winWidth)/2
 centerY=(screen.height-winHeight)/2
 window.moveto centerX,centerY
 posX=0
 posY=0
 move=0
 Function closeHTA()
 self.close
 End Function
 Function setPos()
 posX=window.event.screenX
 posY=window.event.ScreenY
 move=1
 End Function
 Function moving()
 If move=1 Then
 moveX=0
 moveY=0
 moveX=window.event.screenX-posX
 moveY=window.event.screenY-posY
 window.moveto(window.screenLeft+moveX),(window.screenTop+moveY)
 setPos()    
 End if
 End Function
 Function stopMoving()
 move=0
 End Function
 </script>

<script language="VBScript"> 
Sub RunProgram1 
Const NORMAL_WINDOW = 1
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "excel.exe", "file://xxx.xlsm", , , NORMAL_WINDOW
End Sub
</script>

</head>

<button type="button" style="position:absolute; top:700px; left:39px; width=86px; " onclick="runprogram1">Refresh</button>

<iframe width=320 height=300 frameborder=0 scrolling=no src="http://xxx"></iframe> 
<iframe width=560 height=220 frameborder=0 scrolling=no src="xxx.htm"></iframe>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I haven't done anything serious in VBScript in a while. Can you use `window.setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`window.setTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453490.aspx), something like this:

```
<script language="VBScript">
    Sub delayedRefresh
        window.location.reload()
    End Sub

    Sub RunProgram1
        Const NORMAL_WINDOW = 1
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        objShell.ShellExecute "excel.exe", "file://xxx.xlsm", , , NORMAL_WINDOW

        Call window.setTimeout(GetRef("delayedRefresh"), 3000)

    End Sub
</script>
```

`3000` is 3 secs in milliseconds, you can adjust the value if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the hole HTA you can try something like that :

```
<button type="button" style="position:absolute; top:700px; left:39px; width=86px; " onclick="self.location.reload()">Reload HTA</button>
```